# Prove that the set $S = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x > 0, y \geq \frac{1}{x} \}$ is closed

Tags: general-topology

I need to prove that the set $S = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x > 0, y \geq \frac{1}{x} \}$ is closed.

Any help?

Comment: this is inverse image some continuous function (try like that)

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to Cameron Buie's (correct) answer I would like to suggest the map from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R$ that maps $(x,y)$ to $xy$. The preimage of $[1,\infty)$ is thus closed. So is its intersection with the closed subspace $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\mid x\ge0\}$. But this is just your set $S$.

Comment: How would you go about evaluating whether or not S is bounded in $\mathbb R^2$? I assume it isn't but can't seem to figure out how

Comment: @piece_and_love: You could try to visualize the set $S$. Do you see how it looks like? From there, it is often just a small step to a formal proof of (un)boundedness?

Comment: $S$ is bounded if $\exists(x_0,y_0)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\exists K\in\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $\forall(x,y)\in E \hspace{0.2cm}d((x_0,y_0),(x,y))=\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2}\leq K$. Seeing that $x$ and $y$ are not bounded above in $\mathbb{R}$ there exists no $K\in\mathbb{R}$ satisfying this bound?

I'm very shaky on this stuff so I apologise if this is completely wrong.

Comment: @piece_and_love: Yes, an alternative characterisation of bounded is: $∃K>0$ s.t. $∀(x,y)\in E$ we have $|x|<K, |y|<K$. In other words, $E$ is inside a square of length $2K$  with center $(0,0)$. So if you can prove that $y$ (or $x$) can become arbitrarily large, then you know that $S$ is not bounded. Feel free to ask if your're still unsure about something.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$H:=\bigl\{\langle x,y\rangle\in\Bbb R^2:x>0\bigr\},$$ given the subspace topology, and consider the function $g:H\to\Bbb R$ given by $$g(x,y)=y-\frac1x.$$ This is continuous (do you know why?), and $S$ is the preimage of the closed set $[0,\infty)$, so is closed in $H$, and so closed in $\Bbb R^2$, since $H$ is a topological subspace of $\Bbb R^2$.

---

**Edit**: Stefan points out (correctly) in the comments that my reasoning above isn't sufficient to conclude that $S$ is closed in $\Bbb R^2$, but only that $S=F\cap H$ for some $F$ closed in $\Bbb R^2$. Rather than abandon my approach completely, or show that no point on the $y$-axis is a limit point of $S$ (which would be sufficient to show that $S$ is closed in $\Bbb R^2$), let me fix it up a bit.

Letting $$\overline H:=\bigl\{\langle x,y\rangle\in\Bbb R^2:x\ge0\bigr\},$$ we define $h:\overline H\to\Bbb R$ by $$h(x,y)=\begin{cases}0 & \text{if }x=0,\\e^{g(x,y)} & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$ Then $h$ turns out to be continuous, and $S$ is the preimage of $[1,\infty)$, so is closed in $\overline H$, and since $\overline H$ is closed in $\Bbb R^2$, then $S$ is closed in $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: $H$ should be closed for $S$ to be closed in $R^2$.

Comment: Fair point, @Stefan. I'll have to justify that differently.